How do European countries notice if I'm spending more than 6 months in a country as not resident (for taxes purposes)?
I know they can easily verify it by checking flights, and my expenditures.. but how do they find out in first place, if nobody submits a request to verify?
For example: I’m resident in France, and I spend more than 6 months in Spain.

This does not appear to be a travel question. It's not clear from your question for what purpose you're asking but this may be more suitable for Expats or for Money, or possibly for Law.

If the police suspect that you are not really a resident where you claim to be they may actually come and check. And if they determine that you are abusing the system they will simply cancel your permit.

@KristvanBesien I'm actually European, I don't need a permit. The question was more like: "how can they suspect?" It sounds like the chances are very little, unless something happens like a car accident etc.

@aneuryzm it depends a lot on your circumstances. In some cases it’s trivial for them. In others it may indeed may quite more difficult.

Somewhat related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/as-a-digital-nomad-is-it-possible-to-live-such-that-one-owes-no-tax-obligation

@jcaron yep: getting paid in crypto for your remote job for an American startup? Can probably get away for decades. Getting paid by a multi national corp that has due diligence checks? Probably won’t last long.

@anoeuryzm: As a European you still need to register with authorities is you take up residence somewhere. And you need to deregister in the place you left. Otherwise the fact that you are not registered at your primary residence my indeed catch up with you.

@KristvanBesien, details on that differ from country to country.

However all countries have in common that they will throw the book (all of them) at you if you are caught evading taxes...

Edited in response to the comments: There are different laws this idea might break, and different ways how this might come to light. Or not -- making it easier to break the law is a consequence of making legitimate border crossings easier.

If you are an EU citizen, you do not need a residence permit. If you are European but not EU, you will. Breaking the terms of the national visa may be difficult to catch, but if you are caught (see below), the consequences are serious.
You mentioned taxes, there are also social security payments which may be due. Avoiding taxes and payments would be a crime and various police and tax authorities would investigate if they have a suspicion.

Employers have a duty to pay taxes, etc., and generally they try to comply with this duty. An employer would generally be interested in knowing where their employees work. In Germany, something called the A1-Bescheinigung is required to prove social security status for temporary work abroad.
Landlords may want to check the residency status of their tenant, if only to gauge the likelihood of getting paid.
In case of sickness, doctors and hospitals would want to be paid, and that may involve the health insurance provider. That provider keeps records.
Tax returns may simply look inconsistent and cause further investigation.



If the authorities start to suspect you of tax evasion, that crime may be investigated by more or less intrusive methods. It is a crime, and the police have various means at their disposal. And  if you are caught, a low-probability event, the consequences may be dire.

If you legitimately live near one of the Schengen internal borders, for practical purposes you can cross every day and get away with breaking the rules. in areas where cross border commuting is common, employers/localities have agreements to direct taxes correctly (eg Geneva/Annemasse)

@MJeffryes, yes, but that would involve telling the authorities and filing the requisite tax forms. The OP seems to assume that one keeps it secret.

@o.m. Thanks for your reply. It is indeed as I thought. I was thinking that landlords surely need to register tenants, but I can also rent a place and leave it for a month and keep paying the rent. So the only way to prove would be to ask airlines to provide the data. In any case, this check will unlikely happen unless something bad happens.

@aneuryzm, landlords registering tenants is a national rule. But remember, tax evasion is usually a crime, and if a criminal investigation starts they have more tools at their disposal than just asking the airline.

@o.m. Yes true. I'm very aware of that. The reason why I'm asking this is that I'm planning to spend less than 6 months abroad overall, so no intention to violate the law. But it could happen that I have to come back 1 month more, so in that case I would need to do papers.

I think the point about cross-border travel is really just muddying the waters and unrelated to the question. What rule is being broken if you cross the border everyday? The question is explicitly about residing in another country and the residence of a cross-border worker is well defined.

Incidentally, in the example raised by @MJeffryes you don't need to tell the authorities anything, in canton Geneva employers withhold income tax for French residents and will collect all your info and report it to the authorities. It's fine not to know but why make stuff up and write a hand-wavy comment about “tax forms” when you clearly have no idea about the way things work in this particular situation?

@Relaxed, this was originally asked in Travel SE, now it is in Expatriates. In neither it is a given that the person in question is an EU/EEA citizen, and that brings national long-term visa and 90/180 into play.

@o.m. That's not the point, it's a completely different subject. The question always was and still is about taxes. You erroneously pretended that crossing the border every day is in itself breaking the rules and now you have to add a lot of hypotheses and irrelevant considerations to find some reason to justify your original mistake. None of this is really improving your answer. It would be much clearer and better if you just edited out all of this and focused on addressing the OP's situation.

To the extent that you really feel you have to have to mention immigration law as well (even though it's not the question) then a simple reminder at the end that staying 6 months straight in Spain on a French residence permit would also be clearer and more relevant than this very contrived notion of “covertly” crossing the border every day.

Also, the A1 document is an EU thing and is nothing specific to Germany (inherently cannot be: its entire purpose is either for Germany to inform other EU countries that someone is covered or to check that a resident from another EU country has coverage, which is why it need to be standardized). Again very confusing to bring that up in a question on France and Spain.

@Relaxed, the question was about "two European countries, e.g. France and Spain." I presumed that means EU and Schengen, but not necessarily those two.

@o.m. Yes, as Relaxed points on, in my specific example it does not involve filling out forms. Your employer knows where you live and delivers tax to the correct authority. As does your bank for that matter. Many (perhaps most?) of these potential loopholes have been filled for most feasible living arrangements.

@aneuryzm "the only way to prove would be to ask airlines to provide the data": air travel is not the only way to cross a border.  Even if one or more airlines has a record of your flying from France to Spain in January and from Spain to France in December, that doesn't necessarily show that you were in Spain for 11 months.

@phoog In my case, the destination would be an island. But yes, it could be via ferry too. But again, I was stressing the point that they won't check.

As pointed out already, it depends on several things.  But since you mentioned Spain, landlords there are also expected to pay taxes.  If they comply, that may expose you.  And if they don’t, they are cheaters, and will likely also try to cheat tenants.  Which will eventually result in a cheated tenant reporting them to Hacienda, resulting in an investigation that will probably expose you.
